# When is it necessary to expand out the first term(s) of a power series?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, laurent-series

I'm comfortable with the process of finding the Laurent series for a complex function, but in many of the answers from the textbook the first few terms will be expanded from it. Since I'm teaching myself this material I suspect it's something conceptual I'm missing.

For example this is an answer I got for a question

$$z^2sin(1/z^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{4n}(2n+1)!},(0<|z|<\infty)$$

And this is the answer from the textbook

$$z^2sin(1/z^2)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{4n}(2n+1)!},(0<|z|<\infty)$$

It seems to me that they are equal and the difference shouldn't matter, but this discrepancy is consistently coming up where the textbook's answers have a term or two expanded. So it feels like I'm missing something here.

Comment: I suspect it is a matter of preference for the author. They could be trying to avoid having to deal with $0^0$ terms, or leaving initial terms expanded to highlight specific behaviour of the series.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x giving $sin x$

Comment: @ConMan There is no $0^0$ term since $0< |z|$ and if you did try $z=0$ you would hit problems with the $1/z^2$ on the left and the $\frac 1{z^{4n}}$ on the right for positive $n$.  The result being close to $1$ for large $|z|$ may be the  point being highlighted, though it is close to $0$ for small $|z|$